# Why doesn't this page query work?

Tags: query-posts

This should be easy. I need to query to display one page in a tab. Just pull one page by one query, but I'm doing something (maybe lots) wrong here:

**Edit: Hah. I forgot `the_content` It works now.**

```
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query; $the_query->query ('pagename=about' );

while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>  //forgot this

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Query works fine for me, try chucking in a `wp_reset_query()` before (and possibly after) your custom query and see if that helps..

Comment: Thanks. That's a good point. But. Arggg... I forgot the_content. Works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah. I forgot `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be `$the_query = new WP_Query('pagename=about');` ?

Comment: Nope, either method is valid..

Comment: Ah ok - I didn't realise have_posts() also executed the query

Answer (score -1):

If there is only one page to call, why use "while"? Look:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query;
$query->query ('pagename=about');
$query->the_post();
the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: Glancing at the comments on [the original question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/13817/), the OP apparently got it to work.